# Как сохранить состояние TreeView после открытия закрытия формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

На форме расположено "TreeView".
Node_1
-- Node_1_1
-- Node_1_2
Node_2
-- Node_2_1
-- Node_2_2

**Сеанс 1**
Открываем форму 
Получаем
"Node_1" - свёрнуто;
"Node_2" - свёрнуто;
Все узлы свёрнуты.
Пользователь разворачивает "Node_2".
Получаем
"Node_1" - свёрнуто;
"Node_2" - развёрнуто;
Закрывает форму.

**Сеанс 2**
Открываем форму.
Получаем
"Node_1" - свёрнуто;
"Node_2" - развёрнуто;

Вопрос.
Как сохранить состояние свёрнуто, развёрнуто для всех узлов всех уровней?

Comment: Одной строкой - никак. Для родного `TreeView` в WinForms даже биндинги нормальные поленились сделать, нужно руками заполнять. Проходите по узлам и сохраняйте в модели дерева, которое должно отображаться, если нет модели - заведите или сохраняйте куда угодно, а при открытии читаете сохраненные данные, если они есть и обновляете, если что-то изменилось.

Comment: @rdom 1. Модель дерева - БД, XML, "*.ini"?
2. Что сохранять? Пример: есть развёрнуты узел. 
Что сохранить чтобы при втором сеансе формы получить этот же развёрнутый узел.

Comment: Сохранять всё, что нужно, чтобы потом при считывании настроить дерево так, как вам надо. Надо вам только флаги развернуто-не развернуто хранить - храните их в паре с указанием к которому узлу флаг относится.

Comment: У узла есть свойство, не могу сейчас посмотреть как точно называется, что-то типа IsExpanded. Вот это свойство и идентификатор узла и сохранять. Причём желательно, чтобы идентификатор отражал не только связь с данными, но и положение узла в дереве, искусственный идентификатор разумеется

Comment: Можете сами написать ответ на свой вопрос, поместив в нем код из другого вашего вопроса. И потом закрыть тему (вам будет плюсик в репутацию).

Comment: @tym3216 пока только разобрался как сохранить в отдельный файл XML дерево, в отдельной файл XML узылы у которых "IsExpanded" = true.
Можно ли сохранить в один XML дерево и свойства узлов?
Буду признателен, если посоветуете несложное решение или пример кода.
Может нужно перебрать дерево рекруссией?

Comment: @rdorn  пока только разобрался как сохранить в отдельный файл XML дерево, в отдельной файл XML узылы у которых "IsExpanded" = true.
Можно ли сохранить в один XML дерево и свойства узлов?
Буду признателен, если посоветуете несложное решение или пример кода.
Может нужно перебрать дерево рекруссией?

Comment: А зачем вам дерево сохранять в файл? Вы же до этого его без файла строили. И приводите что пытаетесь в вопросе, писать что вы делали без кода смысла не имеет